# Reading multiple files serially without using readFileSync() in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, fs

If using readFileSync method, I can complete my objective in the following code:

```
// Array of the file names
const files = [
    'a.txt',
    'b.txt',
    'c.txt'
]

for (let i=0;i < files.length();i++) {
    let result = fs.readFileSync(files[i]);
    console.log(files[i] + "  " + result.length);
}

console.log('done');
```

So, if I can't use  readFileSync method, how to get same output?

I am using node v6.10.3, so I do not have `util.promisify()`, but I do have almost complete `Promise` support.

Comment: Do you actually care that the files are opened and read in order, or just that the output in the console is in order?

Comment: just  the output in the console is in order

Comment: Just a small nitpick, `files.length` is a number, not a function.

Comment: Why can't you use readFileSync? Knowing this and any other info about your environment will be instructive.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) and [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), you can do the following, which reads all the files asynchronously in parallel and provides the buffers in order when all operations are complete. Below also contains a polyfill for `util.promisify()` for node versions less than v8.0.0 that have support for `Promise` and ECMAScript 6:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
// const util = require('util')

function promisify (fn) {
  return function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fn.call(this, ...arguments, (error, value) => {
        if (error) reject(error)
        else resolve(value)
      })
    })
  }
}

const files = [
  'a.txt',
  'b.txt',
  'c.txt'
]

// const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile)

Promise.all(files.map(file => readFile(file))).then(
  results => results.forEach((result, index) => {
    console.log(files[index], result.length)
  })
)
```

Just to explain a bit about what's going on here with `util.promisify()` magic, it turns this node-style callback:

```js
fs.readFile(file, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // handle result
  }
})
```

into this promise:

```js
util.promisify(fs.readFile)(file).then(result => {
  // handle result
}, error => {
  // handle error
})
```

But we're instead keeping a reference to the function returned by `util.promisify(fs.readFile)` in the variable `readFile`, so that it can be called for each `file`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't use Promise. The only thing I can use is callback and javascript.

Comment: @vincent that should have been mentioned in the question. Regardless of what you're supposed to use though, this is the best practice. Achieving this with callbacks is a lot messier, which is why promises have replaced them as the standard API for asynchronous control flow.

Comment: `The only thing I can use is callback and javascript.` -- and tell your professor that [`Promise.prototype.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) _is_ a callback, and it _is_ part of the core language specification, and that it should be taught instead of (or at least in addition to) the archaic node-style callback API in your class.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. But your code have an error. util.promisify is not a function.

Comment: @vincent again _read the documentation_ for `util.promisify()`, it was introduced in node v8.0.0. Run `node -v` to figure out what version you have. This is not an error on my part but an assumption on yours.

Comment: my node version is v6.10.3. That's why I just want to use callback. My friend told me using recursive to do this. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192918/discussion-between-vincent-and-patrick-roberts).

Comment: v6.10.3 is a little over two years old now, you might want to consider updating to the latest stable.